# Jquery: How do you strip out form and div tags to isolate a piece of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to strip this block of html:

```
<form>
   <h3>Some Title</h3>
   <div class="grab_this_content">
      This sentence is what I want remaining.
   </div>
</form>
```

into this just this:

```
This sentence is what I want remaining.
```

I know how to strip the form tags like so:

```
  $form = $('form');
  $form.replaceWith($form.html());
```

...which results in:

```
   <h3>Some Title</h3>
   <div class="grab_this_content">
      This sentence is what I want remaining.
   </div>
```

But that still leaves me with the h3 tag as well as the div (div class="grab_this_content") tags inside the html block, which I want to also strip away. Any ideas on how to strip the above HTML block and just leave the sentence I want remaining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy as pie:

```
$('form').replaceWith($('div .grab_this_content', 'form').text());
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y46m4/)

Answer (score 3):

you can get the div's html, like

```
$('form').replaceWith($("div.grab_this_content").html())
```